# Как сделать адаптивно блок с таблицей?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Есть вот такая шахматная верстка, хочу сделать адаптивность, можно с использованием Bootstrap. Но когда дошло до адаптивности я ума не приложу как это сделать, ведь в `tr`я не могу вставить `<div class="row"></div>`. Мне кажется что я не правильно сделал эту верстку с шахматными блоками.
Прошу вашего совета.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 font-family: Calibri;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.wrapper{
 width: 1170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: #eefaf9;
}
/*.shahmatka{
 background-color: #eefaf9;
}*/
.shahmatka td{
 width: 168px;
 height: 168px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.shahmatka .item{
 padding-left: 17px;
 padding-top: 30px;
 color: #fff; 
}
.img{
 width: 168px;
 height: 168px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
/*вот так сделал шахматную доску :) */
.shahmatka tr:first-child td:nth-child(odd){
 border: 1px solid #44c3be;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
.shahmatka tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(even){
 border: 1px solid #44c3be;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
.shahmatka tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(odd){
 border: 1px solid #44c3be;
 background: #0cb1aa;
}
.shahmatka .info{
 background: #14cac2 !important;
 color: black !important;
 vertical-align: top;
 font-size: 45px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left: 51px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
/*Блок растянутый в таблице*/
.shahmatka .title{
 height: 150px;
 background-color: #04726d;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.block-center {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: flex;
 width: 1170px;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 align-content: center;
 padding: 51px;
 background: #04726d;
 color: #ffffff;
 height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="shahmatka">
   <div class="row">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="info"><p>Блоки обучения</p></td>
        <td style="display:none;"></td>
    <td><p class="item">АРТ</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img2.png')"></td>
    <td><p class="item">СПОРТ</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img3.png')"></td>
    <td><p class="item">STEM</p></td>
   </tr>
   </div>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><p class="item">Гуманитарный блок</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img4.png')"></td>
    <td><p class="item">ІТ</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img5.png')"></td>
    <td><p class="item">МЕДИА</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img6.png')"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><p class="item">PERFOMANS</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img1.png')"></td>
    <td><p class="item">ПОЛИГЛОТ</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img7.png')"></td>
    <td><p class="item">БИЗНЕС</p></td>
    <td class="img" style="background-image: url('./img/img8.png')"></td>
    <td><p class="item">Социальная ответственность</p></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без media queris сложно будет её адаптировать .. собственно там всего одну цифру поменять , смотрите ...

**1 вариант** ...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  background: blue;
}

.c {
  background: green;
}

.e {
  background: pink;
}

.grid {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto
}

.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="content">

    <table id="table" cellspacing="0">

      <tr>
        <td class="a" colspan="2"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="c"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="c"></td>
        <td class="e"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="e"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="c"></td>
        <td class="e"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="e"></td>
      </tr>


    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

**2 вариант** , *такой какой надо* ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.a {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.b {
  background: #fff;
}

.c {
  background: lightgreen;
  filter: brightness(60%);
}

.box {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 40%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="content">
    <table id="table">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="c"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
        <td class="b"></td>
        <td class="a"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, я сейчас как раз делаю на флексбоксах + медиа запросы. У вас же не могу понять почему криво встают новые блоки? ведь мне нужно по 7 в строке разместить, но в первом нужно 6

Comment: вот сделал как на вашем примере

Comment: @ Максим Ленский спасибо!